# Camel-Kafka security protocol SASL_PLAINTEXT not supported

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, kerberos, cloudera

I need to route ActiveMQ messages to Kafka(Cloudera) using Camel using authentication protocol Kerberos.

- ActiveMQ v5.15.4
- Camel:2.21.1
- Kafka Clients: 1.1.0
- Server Version: Apache/2.4.6(CentOS)

Kafka Security documentation states that it only supports **SASL_PLAINTEXT** and
**SASL_SSL** for Kerberos

On the other hand when I try to use **SASL_PLAINTEXT** for security protocol in Camel I  am getting an error during the ActiveMQ starting. As a result ActiveMQ will not start.

I took the latest Camel code from: https://github.com/apache/camel.git and it states that it only supports **SSL** and **PLAINTEXT** as security protocols values.

I did find this solved issue: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3364871 but I did not find any evidence that this is working in the latest Camel version.

My Camel setup fragment is:

```
<log message="Started The Producer Route" />
<to uri="kafka://10.100.70.00:9092?topic=MyEvents.s1.v1&amp;brokers=10.100.70.00:9092&amp;requestTimeoutMs=305000&amp;retries=3&amp;keySerializerClass=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer&amp;saslMechanism=GSSAPI&amp;serializerClass=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer&amp;securityProtocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT&amp;saslKerberosServiceName=kafka"/>
```

I am using an external Jaas configuration file.

Is it true that Camel does not support **SASL_PLAINTEXT**?

Answer (score 1):

Camel supports **SASL_PLAINTEXT** as it uses Kafka client v1.1.0. The problem is that the actual security parameter is not propagated to the Camel interface. That means the parameter is not recognised during ActiveMQ startup.
I've opened [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12596) for this problem.